# TV show about a senior crew member who has to leave the base to see his daughter and give her a dog

Tags: story-identification, tv

I thought it was an episode of *Stargate* but now I can't find it. I think there was a facility or base in which the crew members worked at, which was on Earth, not a ship and there would be workers coming and going into it. I remember a scene where one of the crew (a senior member, I think) needed to go out of the facility to see a child, a female child, possibly his daughter(?).

I think he and his wife weren't together, that they'd maybe had a falling out (more than once?), throughout the show. I remember him going to a park or a grassy area and the girl is there with a female (maybe his wife ) ... and he gives the child a dog she's wanted. There's a small part of me that thinks maybe the child isn't human but doesn't know it and he is leaving her there. He then returns to the facility. It was an emotional scene.

Comment: Could this be [SG1: Singularity](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Singularity)? The scene with the dog is here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRzo_DCilKA

Comment: I agree with Valorum. This does sound like the "Singularity" episode of Stargate SG1, although the bit about having to go off-base to see Cassandra sounds like you might be mixing elements of another episode in which Cassandra appears (she also appears in episodes "In the Line of Duty", and "Rite of Passage").

Comment: @Valorum seems like a match, kick that one out of unanswered tab?

Comment: @Jenayah - Post it if you want to. It didn't seem like a very good match to me,  more of a mish-mash of different episodes.